# All TLS requests giving Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user

Tags: linux, shell, ssl

When I try an https request to google.com, I just recently started seeing

```
[root@ip-172-31-47-76 ~]# curl -I -v https://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 216.58.193.78...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (216.58.193.78) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.google.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*       start date: Feb 20 14:17:23 2018 GMT
*       expire date: May 15 14:08:00 2018 GMT
*       common name: *.google.com
*       issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
* NSS error -8172 (SEC_ERROR_UNTRUSTED_ISSUER)
* Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

This is affecting my ability to update the system as yum update requests fail as well. I've tried reimporting my certificates using the instructions on this page: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003. I've also tried manually adding Google cert using the instructions here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html. Neither worked.

I'm not sure if it's related but I tried troubleshooting further with the certutil utility but that can't be run

```
[root@ip-172-31-47-76 ~]# certutil
certutil: /usr/local/firefox/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.30' not found (required by certutil)
```

Not quite sure what happened here but I would appreciate any help.  This is using an Amazon Linux image.

Comment: I have similar issue with cloudflare orgin certificate. (I have installed their root cert also)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't simulate your error, but I believe It will work after manually updating the certificate.
For this, you can use 'openssl' tool, the easy way to get extract the CA cert for a particular server:

**1.** Get the server public certificate and save to file conn_cert.log.pem typing the command bellow (and press enter)

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername https://google.com -connect google.com:443 > conn_cert.log.pem
```

**2.** Now, type "quit" and press Enter

**3.** The file "conn_cert.log.pem" has the Certificate between "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" and "END CERTIFICATE" strings, but it has other log messages, now we gonna extract only the certificate from the log file and save it within the file "google_public.crt".

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in conn_cert.log.pem -text -out google_public.crt
```

**4.** Finally, overwrite the bad certificate with the new one:

```
cp google_public.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

**5.** Test again and have be happy..

REFs:

- [SSL Certificate Verification](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)

Comment: Same issue. Manually providing certificates doesn't help (and can't reasonably be done for every server we want to access). Files in `/etc/pki/nssdb` and `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` are exactly the same (same checksum) as those on a server without any problems.